# Installing drool package in Azure databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I have started learning Azure DataBricks few days back and was trying to install drools compiler in Azure databricks cluster. Here is the information about my cluster:

Cluster Mode: Standard
Databricks runtime version: 7.2 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.0, Scala 2.12)

The maven package which I am trying to install is "org.drools:drools-compiler:7.42.0.Final" and it fails with error

*Library resolution failed. Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: unresolved dependency: xmlpull:xmlpull:1.2.0: not found
unresolved dependency: xpp3:xpp3_min:1.2.0: not found*

Even installing (xpp3) or (xmlpull) [ xpp3:xpp3_min:1.2.0 or xmlpull:xmlpull:1.2.0 ] is failing with same error.

Would appreciate any help or pointers on this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to install via maven coordinates, I have received the same error message. It looks like some issue with the missing of dependencies (there is no artifact called drools-compiler).

**Alternate solution which helps to install library:**

You can directly download the library from maven repository and upload to the cluster.

**Step1:** Download the library from the maven repository.

**Example:** I have download (org.drools:drools-compiler:7.42.0.Final) jar file from the maven repository.

[image]

**Step2:** Select the cluster => Libraries => Install New => Library Type "Jar" => Drop the download Jar here and click Install.

[image]

[image]

[image]